# How can I properly sanitize integer fields in Symfony2 forms?

Tags: php, symfony

Under perfect circumstances, a user submits only numbers - no commas, periods, or letters. This is fine for Chrome because Chrome doesn't allow these characters in an integer input. But what about browsers that don't prevent this? If a user decides to put a comma in, Symfony gets unexpected results.

Example of a good input:
[image]

Example of a bad input:
[image]

```
public function Debug4Action(Request $request){

        $inquiry = new Inquiry();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($inquiry)
            ->add('revenueMin', 'integer');

        $form = $form->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            var_dump($form->getData()->getRevenueMin());
            return new Response('');
        }

        return $this->render('render_form.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

When a user submits the bad input into this `var_dump($form->getData()->getRevenueMin());` outputs `NULL`.

The Symfony docs describe a process of transforming data after submission by using the `addModalTransformer()` method. This seems like it would be a perfect fit for this use case. I have tried to manually scrub out any non numeric characters and continue processing the input.

```
public function Debug5Action(Request $request){

        $inquiry = new Inquiry();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($inquiry)
            ->add('revenueMin', 'integer');

        /*
         * Symfony2 docs recommend using a this to transform the data into something usable.
         * More info: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html
         */
        $form->get('revenueMin')->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function($originalInput){
                //As far as I know, this isn't relevant, but CallbackTransformer requires two anonymous functions.
                return $originalInput;
            },
            function($submittedValue){
                //I don't know if this works on integers - but let's see what happens.
                $submittedValue = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $submittedValue);
                return $submittedValue;
            }
        ));

        $form = $form->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            var_dump($form->getData()->getRevenueMin());
            return new Response('');
        }

        return $this->render('render_form.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

However, now we get slightly different results. `var_dump($form->getData()->getRevenueMin());` now outputs an empty string. I would guess that this occurs because `preg_replace()` returns an empty sting with being used on `NULL`.

The final attempt changes the field type to a text input.

```
 public function Debug6Action(Request $request){

        $inquiry = new Inquiry();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($inquiry)
            //Notice that the form input is now text.
            ->add('revenueMin', 'text');

        $form->get('revenueMin')->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function($originalInput){
                return $originalInput;
            },
            function($submittedValue){
                $submittedValue = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $submittedValue);
                //Cast the string into an int for processing.
                return (integer) $submittedValue;
            }
        ));

        $form = $form->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            var_dump($form->getData()->getRevenueMin());
            return new Response('');
        }

        return $this->render('render_form.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

This last attempt returns exactly what I need to process the submission! `var_dump($form->getData()->getRevenueMin());` outputs `int(1234)`. However, because I've rendered the form as *text* instead of *integer*, I am missing out on some of the HTML5 form elements that would have been built had I built the form with an integer type.

How can I display an integer form input to users but continue to get sanitized integers to process?

Comment: is the entity property of field type integer ?

Comment: I haven't provided it _any_ data type. It isn't being stored and does not require an `@Column` declaration at all. Unless there is another way to set a field type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon further research it looks like some browsers (I'm working with Safari) will not send **anything** in a field if the input requires an integer value and an integer is not provided.

Consider the following code:

```
<!--test.html-->
<form name="form" method="post" action="test2.php">
    <label>revenueMin</label>
    <input type="number" id="form_revenueMin" name="form[revenueMin]"/><br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

---

```
<?php
    //test2.php
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Inputting 1,234 results in:

```
array(1) { ["form"]=> array(1) { ["revenueMin"]=> string(0) "" } }
```

Inputting 1234 results in:

```
array(1) { ["form"]=> array(1) { ["revenueMin"]=> string(4) "1234" } }
```

Because this is a browser issue and not a Symfony issue, the only solution is the third solution provided in the question.

Also worth noting, the second input still gets sent as a string, so casting it as an integer manually is still required.